# How can I do an inner join inside of a subquery? MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to adapt this select statement to my tables. This query selects all of the zip codes from a zip code table that are within a certain distance of a given zip code. However, I have a Salon table that stores the zip codes as a foreign from the zip code table. I need to select all of the salons within a certain distance of the given zip code.

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE zip_search(lat_param FLOAT(9,6),
     long_param FLOAT(9,6), dist_param INT(100)
    )
    BEGIN
    SELECT zipcode
      FROM (
     SELECT z.zipcode, z.latitude, z.longitude,
            p.radius,
            p.distance_unit
                     * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                     * COS(RADIANS(z.latitude))
                     * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint - z.longitude))
                     + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                     * SIN(RADIANS(z.latitude)))) AS distance
      FROM accounts_zip AS z
      JOIN (   /* these are the query parameters */
            SELECT  lat_param  AS latpoint,  long_param AS longpoint,
                    dist_param AS radius,      69.0 AS distance_unit
        ) AS p ON 1=1
      WHERE z.latitude
         BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
             AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
        AND z.longitude
         BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
             AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
     ) AS d
     WHERE distance <= radius
     ORDER BY distance;
    END //
```

I tried adding an inner join after selecting from the salon table, however I do not understand sub queries and joins very well. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
DELIMITER //
        CREATE PROCEDURE zip_search(lat_param FLOAT(9,6),
         long_param FLOAT(9,6), dist_param INT(100)
        )
        BEGIN
        SELECT *
          FROM (
         SELECT z.zipcode, z.latitude, z.longitude,
                p.radius,
                p.distance_unit
                         * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                         * COS(RADIANS(z.latitude))
                         * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint - z.longitude))
                         + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                         * SIN(RADIANS(z.latitude)))) AS distance
          FROM accounts_salon INNER JOIN accounts_zip ON accounts_salon.id=accounts_zip.id AS z
          JOIN (   /* these are the query parameters */
                SELECT  lat_param  AS latpoint,  long_param AS longpoint,
                        dist_param AS radius,      69.0 AS distance_unit
            ) AS p ON 1=1
          WHERE z.latitude
             BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
                 AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
            AND z.longitude
             BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
                 AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
         ) AS d
         WHERE distance <= radius
         ORDER BY distance;
        END //
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the ' AS z' in first inner join is necessary, if you try to get the join result of tables accounts_salon and accounts_zip, and treat it as the left table of second inner join, then just continure write the next inner join.